# CSS light (fading) effect

Tags: css, fading

[image]

I found this picture on the internet and I would love to do this effect on my website. 
I am trying to have a darker background, a lamp at the top like on the picture and a picture under it. But I want it to look like the light from the lamp is shining on a picture. 
Is this possible to do?

Comment: Just have a transparent `png` of the lighting effect and put it on top of your picture to show. Real simple.

Comment: As in a transparent picture of just the lamp and the light ? But if I put that picture over my picture then would it not cover the gallery picture?

Comment: Not if it's transparent surely, it'll just put the effect on top. Like layers in photoshop or something.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a few pseudo elements to create this effect, including a linear gradient and transforms:

**Demo [hover image to see effect]**

```css
.light {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.light img {/*Image inside*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.light:before {/*creates the bulb*/
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;/*places above image*/
  left: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: translateX(-50%);/*places in center of image*/
  z-index: 10;/*places in front of image*/
  border: 2px solid dimgray;/*borders add 3D effect to bulb*/
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 5px solid #222;
}

.light:after {/*creates the beam*/
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);/*centers, makes as trapezium*/
  transform-origin: top center;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8));/*adds fading light*/
  z-index: 5;/*places in front of image, but behind bulb*/
}

.light:hover:after {/*demo only, add this to .light:after in production*/
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="light">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is so cool. How did you make light image like that? And I would like for the light to stay down over the picture instead of having it on hover.

Comment: Rather than have `height:80%;` declared in the hover state, place this into the `.light:after` css definition. The light 'bulb' was made in the `.light:before`, whilst the light 'beam' was made in the `light:after` css

Comment: But do I not need an actual picture of the lightbulb first?

Comment: I've not used an image. I've created one in css

Answer (score 0):

Add **opacity:0.9;** or **opacity:0.3;** to your darker background image style..
Hope this help's...

Comment: Well I dont have a background image yet. I am using the picture above as a background image. But I would like to have a different background and just the lamp effect on top of it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transparent png image like @Eamonn said or use gradient and shadow in CSS like in sample below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.light {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20%;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px 5px #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 66%, rgba(255,255,255,0.79) 76%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 66%,rgba(255,255,255,0.79) 76%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 1%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 66%,rgba(255,255,255,0.79) 76%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
</style>
<div class="light"></div>
```